# How to remove extraneous vertical space between html elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have a problem with spacing between form fields (and other HTML elements) as seen in the attached images. I've tried many things in the CSS but nothing has worked. I'm not sure if it's a paragraph marging-top setting.

thanks for the help.

[image]

[image] .post-content is the class here and div.post-share for the facebook like buttons.

here's my style.css code:

```
body {
background: #f2f2f2;
padding-top: 58px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.postid-1699 { padding-top: 338px; }

a {
color: #9f9f9f;
}

a:hover {
color: #3f3f3f;
}

a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div {
word-wrap: break-word;
}

h1, h2, h3 { letter-spacing: -1px;
}


/* Masonry */
#masonry {
margin: 0 auto;
visibility: hidden;
}

#masonry .thumb {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
font-size: 0.9em;
float: left;
margin: 0 8px 14px 8px;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #D6D6D6;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #D6D6D6;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #D6D6D6;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}


#masonry .featured-thumb-link {
display: block;
min-height: 70px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

#masonry .featured-thumb-gif {
background: transparent url("img/gif_overlay.png") no-repeat;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
position: absolute;
}

#masonry .sticky {
background: #ffd;
}

#masonry .masonry-actionbar {
display: none;
font-weight: normal;
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 5px;
width: 250px;
z-index: 999;
}

#masonry .masonry-actionbar button {
font-weight: normal;
}

#masonry .masonry-actionbar-mobile {
display: none;
}

#masonry .post-title {
line-height: 1.3em;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 3px 0 16px 0;
padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
text-align: center;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta {
border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
clear: both;
color: #888;
font-size: 0.9em;
line-height: 1.3em;
padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-author {
font-weight: bold;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-comment-likes {
border-top: none;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 0;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-comment-likes span {
margin: 0 0.3em;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-comment {
margin-left: 35px;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-comment-content {
white-space: pre-wrap;  
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-avatar {
float: left;
margin: 2px 0px 5px 0;
width: 26px;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta-avatar img {
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
}

#masonry #reply-title {
}

#masonry .masonry-meta textarea {
height: 27px;
margin-top: 2px;
padding-top: 2px;
resize: none;
width: 100%;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#masonry .masonry-meta form {
margin: 0;
}

#ajax-loader-masonry {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -12px;
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
}

#infscr-loading { 
background: #000;
bottom: 0;
color: #fff;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;
opacity: 0.3;
padding: 5px;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
width: 120px;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-text-shadow: none;
-moz-text-shadow: none;
text-shadow: none;
}

#infscr-loading img {
width: 43px;
}

#post-lightbox {
background: transparent;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#post-lightbox .post-wrapper {
position : static;
width: 570px;
margin: 25px auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


/* Post */
#post-masonry {
position: relative
}

.post-wrapper {
background: transparent;
border: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
margin-bottom: 45px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
z-index: 200;
}

.post-wrapper .h1-wrapper {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.post-wrapper .h1-wrapper h1 {
font-size: 1.5em;
line-height: 1.3em;
margin: 10px 25px;
text-align: center;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
min-height: 48px;
padding: 20px 25px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper-header .follow {
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 8px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper-header {
color: #999;
margin-left: 60px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper-author {
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.2em;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper-header a {
color: #000;
}

.post-wrapper .post-share {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 320px;
}

.post-share-horizontal {
background: #fafafa;
display: block;
padding: 8px 8px 0 8px;
}

.post-share-horizontal #___plusone_0, .post-share-horizontal #___plusone_1 {
margin-left: -25px !important;
margin-right: -15px !important;
padding-bottom: 13px !important;
}

.post-share .fb_iframe_widget {
display: block;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 90px;
}

.post-share .fb_iframe_widget span {
width: 450px !important;    
}

.post-comments-wrapper .fb_iframe_widget span, .post-comments-wrapper .fb_iframe_widget  {
width: 100% !important;
}

.post-share-horizontal .pinterest img, .post-share-horizontal .post-embed, .post-share-horizontal .post-email, .post-share-horizontal #post-email-board, .post-share-horizontal .post-report {
margin-top: -14px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-meta {
margin: 0 25px;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-meta .pull-right {
color: #a1a1a1;
font-size: 0.9em;
}

.post-wrapper .post-top-meta .pull-right a  {
font-weight: bold;
}

.post-wrapper .post-actionbar {
font-weight: normal;
}

.post-wrapper .post-actionbar button {
font-weight: normal;
}

.post-wrapper .post-actionbar .btn {
margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.post-wrapper .featured-thumb {
position: relative; 
}

.post-wrapper .post-featured-photo {
background: #f2f2f2;
margin: 24px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-next {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -10px;
top: 50%;
right: -18px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-prev {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -10px;
top: 50%;
left: -18px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-next a, .post-wrapper .post-nav-prev a {
display: block;
font-size: 15px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-next a:hover, .post-wrapper .post-nav-prev a:hover {
color: #555;
text-decoration: none;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-link-lightbox {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height: 32px;
line-height: 32px;
width: 32px;
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-link-lightbox i {
display: block;
line-height: 32px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-next-lightbox, .post-wrapper .post-nav-prev-lightbox {
position: fixed;
}

.post-wrapper .post-nav-link-lightbox:hover {
border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.post-wrapper .post-content {
margin: 25px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-content h1 {
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

.post-wrapper .post-content .post-title-large {
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1em;
}

.post-wrapper .post-original-author {
color: #999;
font-size: 0.9em;
}

.post-wrapper .post-original-author a {
font-weight: bold;
}

.post-wrapper .post-content .thecontent img {
height: auto;
}

.post-wrapper .post-comments {
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-comments-wrapper {
margin: 0 25px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board {
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-wrapper {
margin: 0 25px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-wrapper h4 {
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-top: 12px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-wrapper .follow {
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: -2px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-wrapper a {
font-weight: bold;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-photo {
background: #fcfcfc;
border-right: 4px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
float: left;
height: 48px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 48px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-photo:nth-child(n+8) {
border-left: 2px solid #fff;
border-right: 3px solid #fff;
}

.post-wrapper .post-board-photo:nth-child(10) {
border-right: none;
}

.post-wrapper .post-likes {
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-likes-wrapper {
margin: 0 25px 5px 25px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-likes-wrapper h4 {
float: left;
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-top: 12px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-likes-wrapper a {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-likes-wrapper .more-likes {
margin-left: 7px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-meta-top {
margin: 0 25px;
padding: 5px 0 15px 0;
}

.post-wrapper .post-likes-avatar {
margin-left: 55px;
}

.post-wrapper #post-repins {
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 10px 0;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper {
margin: 0 25px 5px 25px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper h4 {
float: left;
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-top: 12px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 62px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper li {
margin-bottom: 6px;
min-height: 50px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper li.more-repins {
min-height: 1em;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper .post-repins-content {
line-height: 1.1em;
margin-left: 55px;
padding-top: 15px;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-wrapper a {
font-weight: bold;
}

.post-wrapper .post-repins-avatar {
margin-right: 4px;
}

.thetags {
margin-top: 6px;
padding: 0;
}

.thetags a {
border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
max-width: 90%;
padding: 2px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.thetags a:hover {
background: #fcfcfc;
text-decoration: none;
}

#post-repin-box {
background: #f2f2f2;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -210px;
max-width: 420px;
position: absolute;
}

#post-repin-box .close {
margin: 3px 8px 0 0;
}

#post-repin-box .post-repin-box-photo {
background: #e1e1e1;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
margin: 5px 25px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}

#post-repin-box .post-repin-box-photo img {
max-height: 300px;
}

#post-repin-box #repinform {
margin: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
}

#post-repin-box .input-prepend, #post-repin-box .input-append {
margin: 0 0 3px 0;
width: 100%;
}

#post-repin-box .add-on {
background-color: #fcfcfc;
color: #999;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 22px;
line-height: 22px;
margin: 3px -1px 0 -1px;
width: 13%;
}

#post-repin-box .input-prepend input, #post-repin-box .input-append input {
font-size: 18px;
height: 32px;
margin: 3px 0;
text-align: left;
width: 84%;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#post-repin-box .input-append input {
text-align: right;  
}

#post-repin-box #repinform select {
font-size: 18px;
height: 32px;
margin: 3px 0 6px 0;
width: 65%;
background: rgb(252,252,252);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,252,252,1) 0%, rgba(241,241,241,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(252,252,252,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(241,241,241,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,252,252,1) 0%,rgba(241,241,241,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,252,252,1) 0%,rgba(241,241,241,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,252,252,1) 0%,rgba(241,241,241,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(252,252,252,1) 0%,rgba(241,241,241,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#f1f1f1',GradientType=0 );
}

#post-repin-box #repinform #noboard select {
color: #999;
}

#post-repin-box #repinform #repinform-add-new-board {
margin-top: 3px;
padding: 6px 10px;
}

#post-repin-box #repinform #board-add-new {
display: none;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 21px;
margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
width: 61%;
}

#post-repin-box #repinform textarea {
font-size: 18px;
height: 4em;
resize: vertical;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#post-repin-box #repinform #pinit {
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px 0;
}

#post-repin-box #repinform .alert {
height: 18px;   
}

#post-repin-box #repinnedmsg {
margin: 0 25px 15px 25px;
}

#post-zoom-overlay {
background: #000;
bottom: 0;
display: none;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1055;
opacity: 0.85;
filter: alpha(opacity=85);
}

#post-embed-overlay {
background: #fff;
bottom: 0;
display: none;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1055;
opacity: 0.92;
filter: alpha(opacity=92);
}

#post-embed-box {
z-index: 1060;
}

#post-embed-box .modal-footer {
text-align: left;
}

#post-embed-box .modal-footer .help-inline {
color: #aaa;
font-size: 1.3em;
margin-top: -10px;
}

#post-embed-box input {
font-size: 1.3em;
padding: 10px;
}

#post-embed-box .modal-footer textarea {
background-color: #f5f5f5;
font-size: 1.3em;
line-height: 1.2em;
height: 6em;
padding: 10px;
resize: none;
width: 100%;    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#post-email-overlay, #post-email-board-overlay {
background: #fff;
bottom: 0;
display: none;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1055;
opacity: 0.92;
filter: alpha(opacity=92);
}

#post-email-box, #post-email-board-box {
z-index: 1060;
}

#post-email-box .modal-footer, #post-email-board-box .modal-footer {
text-align: left;
}

#post-email-box .modal-footer .help-inline, #post-email-board-box .modal-footer .help-inline {
color: #aaa;
font-size: 1.3em;
margin-top: -10px;
}

#post-email-box input, #post-email-board-box input {
font-size: 1.3em;
padding: 10px;
}

#post-email-box .modal-footer textarea, #post-email-board-box .modal-footer textarea {
font-size: 1.3em;
line-height: 1.2em;
height: 6em;
padding: 10px;
resize: none;
width: 100%;    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#post-report-overlay {
background: #fff;
bottom: 0;
display: none;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1055;
opacity: 0.92;
filter: alpha(opacity=92);
}

#post-report-box {
z-index: 1060;
}

#post-report-box .modal-footer {
text-align: left;
}

#post-report-box .modal-footer .help-inline {
color: #aaa;
font-size: 1.3em;
margin-top: -10px;
}

#post-report-box input {
font-size: 1.3em;
padding: 10px;
}

#post-report-box .modal-footer textarea {
font-size: 1.3em;
line-height: 1.2em;
height: 6em;
padding: 10px;
resize: none;
width: 100%;    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.subpage-title h1 {
font-size: 1.8em;
line-height: 1.2em;
padding-bottom: 0.6em;
margin-bottom: 5px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}

.subpage-title p {
border-top: 3px double #ccc;
padding: 8px 0;
text-align: center;
}

.grand-title-wrapper {
margin: 30px 0 60px 0;
text-align: center;
}

.grand-title-wrapper h1 {
border-bottom: 3px double #ccc;
font-size: 1.8em;
line-height: 1.2em;
padding-bottom: 0.6em;
margin-bottom: 5px;
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}

.grand-title-wrapper h1 a {
font-weight: bold;
}

.grand-title-wrapper .grand-title-subheader {
border-bottom: 3px double #ccc;
padding: 4px 0 8px 0;
}

.grand-title-wrapper .grand-title-subheader .avatar {
height: 32px;
width: 32px;
}

.grand-title-wrapper .grand-title-subheader a {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}

.grand-title-wrapper .grand-title-subheader .pull-left a {
margin-right: 5px;
}

.grand-title-wrapper .follow {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}


/* Comments */
.post-comments .commentlist {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.post-comments .commentlist li {
list-style: none;
padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.post-comments .commentlist ul.children li {
margin: 1em 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
}

.post-comments .comment-avatar {
float: left;
padding: 3px 10px 0 0;
}

.post-comments .comment .pull-right a {
padding: 2px 6px;
font-size: 0.8em;
line-height: 15px;
color: #888;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
*background-color: #e6e6e6;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
border: 1px solid #ddd;
*border: 0;
border-bottom-color: #ccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
*margin-left: .3em;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);  
}

.post-comments .comment .pull-right a:hover {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
*background-color: #d9d9d9;
background-position: 0 -15px;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
-o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}

.post-comments .comment-content {
color: #333;
line-height: 1.3em;
margin-left: 60px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
width: 80%;
}

.post-comments span.bypostauthor a.url {
background-color: #aaa;
color: #fff;
margin-right: 5px;
padding: 0 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.post-comments span.bypostauthor a.url:hover {
background-color: #990000;
text-decoration: none;
}

.post-comments #reply-title {
color: #666;
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.post-comments #cancel-comment-reply-link {
margin-left: 60px;
}

.post-comments blockquote p {
font-size: 1em;
}

#commentform .commentform-input {
color: #666;
margin-right: 14px;
width: 31%;
}

#commentform .commentform-input:nth-child(3) {
margin-right: 0;
}

#commentform .commentform-field {
width: 94%;
}

#commentform .textarea-wrapper {
margin-left: 60px;
}

#commentform textarea {
background: #fafafa;
height: 48px;
resize: vertical;
width: 100%;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Media Queries */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #post-lightbox .post-wrapper {
    width: 570px;
    }

    #commentform .commentform-input {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 32%;
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar-left-single {
    width: 270px;
    }

    .sidebar-right-single {
    margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .board-mini {
    width: 270px;
    }

    .board-mini .board-photo-wrapper {
    height: 65.5px;
    width: 65.5px;
    }

    .board-domain .board-domain-wrapper {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-share {
    margin-left: 320px;
    }

    .usercp-pins #pin-upload-postdata-wrapper form .input-prepend input, .usercp-pins #pin-upload-postdata-wrapper form .input-append input {
    width: 85%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
    body {
    padding-top: 0;
    }


    #post-lightbox .post-wrapper {
    width: 460px;
    }

    .sidebar {
    padding-top:0;  
    }

    .sidebar .sidebar-left-single {
    width: 166px;
    }

    .board-mini {
    width: 166px;
    }

    .board-mini .board-photo-wrapper {
    height: 39.5px;
    width: 39.5px;
    }

    .board-domain .board-domain-wrapper {
    height: 29px;
    width: 29px;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-share {
    margin-left: 260px;
    }

    .post-top-meta .pull-right {
    clear:both;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }

    #double-left-column {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #scrolltotop {
    right: 5px
    }

    #scrolltotop a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    }

    #commentform .commentform-input {
    margin-right: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    }

    #commentform .commentform-field {
    width: 98%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    #pin-postdata-add-new-board {
    float: left;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidebar .sidebar-left-single, .post-share {
    display: none;
    }

    .sidebar-right-single {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-board {
    display: block; 
    }

    .post-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .board-mini {
    width: 166px;
    }

    #userbar .nav {
    display: block;
    }

    .usercp-pins #pin-upload-postdata-wrapper form .input-prepend input, .usercp-pins #pin-upload-postdata-wrapper form .input-append input {
    width: 85%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {

#shadowtop { margin-top: -5px; 
}

    #masonry .thumb {
    width: 93%;
    }

    #masonry .featured-thumb {
    height: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    }

    #masonry .masonry-actionbar-mobile {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #post-repin-box {
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    }

    #post-repin-box select {
    max-width: 50%;
    }

    #post-repin-box .post-repin-box-photo img {
    max-height: 150px;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-board-photo:nth-child(n+8) {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-board-photo:nth-child(10) {
    border-right: none;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper-header .follow {
    margin-top: -40px;
    }

    .post-wrapper .post-top-wrapper-header {
    clear: both;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    }

    .board-mini {
    width: 88%;
    }

    .board-mini .board-photo-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 35px;
    width: 24.5%;
    }

    #user-profile-follow .follow-wrapper {
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 90%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #masonry .thumb {
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-right: 13px;
    }

    #shadowtop { margin-top: -2px; 
}
```

Comment: please include your HTML too pls

Comment: @hanumanDev please paste your complete here to better understand your problem..

Comment: Why don't you give us only the relevant css code? Some HTML code would also be appreciated ([link](http://jsfiddle.net) would be perfect)

Answer (score 0):

it was a Google Web fonts plugin that caused it. I disabled the plugin and the problem went away.

this is from the HTML source code:

p {
margin-top: 269px; margin-bottom: 188px; 
}